# Dividing values in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have created a new terminal in a Jupyter notebook.

When I type `3 / 2` I get `1`

How do I obtain `1.5`?

I have selected type code.

Comment: Looks like you are using a Python 2.   Try `3,/2` or something similar, to trigger floating point division.

Comment: I removed the `jupyter` tags since this is a Python question (and a duplicate at that)

Answer (score 0):

You need at least one of two operands to be floating point number. Your problem occurs as in Python 2 the default behaviour when dividing two `int` is try to do the integer division (no decimals).

So try forcing them to be float numbers by typing explicitly the decimal part like `3.0 / 2` or `3 / 2.0` or even converting both sides `3.0 / 2.0`.

Answer (score -2):

You're definitively not using Python 3 as you can see in this example:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 3/2
1.5
>>>
```

Dividing 3 by 2 will definitively evaluate to 1.5. If you would want to have an integer division you'd need to use the operator `//` instead of `/`:

```
>>> 3//2
1
>>>
```

So check your Python version first before looking for any other reason why you don't get `1.5`!

Please note that Python 2 is outdated for about 11 years now. If you're using a Jupyter notebook with Python 2 there's likely something wrong with the Jupyter notebook installation.